# How to use JOIN on database.

Tags: c#, sqlite, foreign-keys

(SQLite and C#)
I have this little problem. See those 2 tables. 1. is parent, 2. is child

[image: Parent]

[image: Child]

I should get "broj_goluba" from parent table to match "par_m" and "par_z" in child table and later just display it in datagridview.

Foregin keys should help to get things done fast, but here when I write code I have much more lines of code opposed to not using foreign keys.

Could someone please help me and write down how *my code* (EDIT: SQL query) should look like when using foreign keys.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve broj_goluba based on par_m or par_z? par_m and par_z are not the same value in any given row, so which one determines which ID to seek on?

Comment: that is right. Database is much larger so I didn't show everything here, but they exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand you need is that, but it doesn't have to do anything with speed. Maybe you mean `INDEX` and not `FOREIGN KEY`.

```sql
SELECT BROJ_GOLUBA
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PAR_M OR TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PAR_J)
```

Or maybe you need BOTH values to be equal:

```sql
SELECT BROJ_GOLUBA
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PAR_M AND TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PAR_J)
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys don't exist to "help to get things done fast". They exist to enforce data integrity. Frankly, I don't see how the number of lines of T-SQL code you write is dependent on whether or not foreign keys exist.

The following query stub should help get you started on your query:

```
Select Table1.broj_goluba, Table2.par_z ...
From Table1
Inner Join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.par_m
```